# jquery stops complete code after calling a little function inside it

Tags: jquery, function

I got a problem with jQuery. I´m changing the great Rhinoslider to my needs. I want to set up a progressbar, which basically works well if the interval-time is not bound to the effect of the slider. But that exactly step is bothering me.

I want my progressbar-function to be executed every time the effect is done (every 10 seconds).

```
//run effect
                if(effects[settings.effect] == undefined){
                    console.log('Preparations for ' + settings.effect + ' not found.');
                }else{
                    //rerun progressbar
                    var progressBar = $('#progress-bar');
                    var barTime = settings.showTime;
                    var barEasing = 'linear';
                    function runProgress2(){
                        progressBar.width(0);
                        progressBar.animate({'width': "+=100%"}, barTime, barEasing);
                    };
                    runProgress2();

                    //do the effect
                    effects[settings.effect]($slider, params, resetElements);
                }
```

You can see, that I called runProgress() directly after printing the whole function. My understanding is, that the browser runs the function and goes on with the effects[settings ...] stuff. But it doesn´t. It simply stops working. The browser does no sliding effect and the progressbar keeps being displayed at 100% width. Total shutdown ... How can I put a statement into that code, for the browser to go on with the execution? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Move the runProgress2 function declaration outside of the else statement and simply call runProgress2();

Comment: Is it just a typo in the question that you declare `runProgress2` but _call_ `runProgress` (without the `2`)?

Comment: thanks for that quick response. basically it works fine. but only for the first time. the second time the bar spreads endless to the right. maybe i have to put that function anywhere else because that "do the effect" thing is only called once ... what do you think?

Comment: at the guy with the n-name. you´re right but I fixed that directly after posting. I´ll edit it right now.